# Installing a specific PyTorch build (f/e CPU-only) with Poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

I've recently found `poetry` to manage dependencies. In one project, we use PyTorch. How do I add this to `poetry`?

We are working on machines that have no access to a CUDA GPU (for simple on the road inferencing/testing) and workstations where we do have access to CUDA GPUs. Is it possible to use poetry to ensure every dev is using the same PyTorch version?

There seems to be no obvious way to decide which PyTorch version to install. I thought about adding the different installation instructions as *extra* dependencies, but I failed to find an option to get the equivalent settings like:

`pip3 install torch==1.3.1+cpu torchvision==0.4.2+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

I would be fine with setting the total path to the different online wheels, like:
`https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html/cpu/torch-1.3.1%2Bcpu-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

But I would rather not but them in git directly... The closest option I've seen in poetry is either downloading them manually and then using `file = X` command.

Comment: I wonder how it'll work if with poetry if we're using the nightly version of pytorch.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Currently, Poetry doesn't have a `-f` option (there's an [open issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1391) and an [open PR](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/1511)), so you can't use the `pip` instructions. You can install the `.whl` files directly:

```
poetry add https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html/cpu/torch-1.3.1%2Bcpu-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

or add the dependency directly to your `.toml` file:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
torch = { url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html/cpu/torch-1.3.1%2Bcpu-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl" }
```

Comment: This is not a satisfying answer as this does not give any solution to the problem being: depending on the platform, point to the correct wheel.

Comment: Note: This won't work if you have dependencies that rely on pytorch, since poetry fails to resolve the dependency versions (https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4231#issue-931746833)

Answer (score 43):

Since poetry 1.2, you can do this:

```
poetry source add --priority explicit pytorch_cpu https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
poetry add --source pytorch_cpu torch torchvision
```

and it will install from the specified index-url.

(and this also works with `https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118` )

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer at the time of writing: it exactly incorporates PyTorch's current official index-url for CPU-only installation and does not require any tools other than poetry itself. Thanks!

Comment: The option "-p" does not exist with Poetry 1.4

Answer (score 17):

After spending a couple of hours on this issue, I found a "solution" by combining Poetry and pip just for PyTorch. You don't need to specify the wheel URLs directly and thus remain cross-platform.

I'm using [Poe The Poet](https://github.com/nat-n/poethepoet), a nice task runner for Poetry that allows to run any arbitrary command.

```
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
poethepoet = "^0.10.0"

[tool.poe.tasks]
force-cuda11 = "python -m pip install torch==1.8.0+cu111 torchvision==0.9.0+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html"
```

You can run:

```
poetry install
```

and then:

```
poe force-cuda11  # relies on pip and use PyTorch wheels repo
```

Answer (score 13):

An updated solution from [this issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2247) in the Poetry github:

```
poetry add torch --platform linux --python "^3.7"
```

Comment: Good link to the issue. Note that this other related issue https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1616 is still open, so this is still an issue and no stable solution is currently available

Comment: This _sort of_ worked for me but I bumped into other (I suspect related) dependency issues further down the track. The [Poe The Poet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66644457/7499546) solution suggested by @Kirell solved my issue though :-)

Comment: How do you specify the cuda version? I'm assuming that command will default to cpu.

Answer (score 11):

In late 2021, utilizing markers and multiple constraints should work.

```
$ poetry --version
Poetry version 1.1.11
```

```
# pyproject.toml
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "~3.9"
torch = [
  {url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.10.0%2Bcpu-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl", markers = "sys_platform == 'linux'"},
  {url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.10.0%2Bcpu-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl", markers = "sys_platform == 'win32'", }
]
numpy = "^1.21.4"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

```
$ poetry install
The currently activated Python version 3.8.12 is not supported by the project (~3.9).
Trying to find and use a compatible version. 
Using python3.9 (3.9.9)
Creating virtualenv machine-learning in /home/redqueen/machine_learning/.venv
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (36.0s)

Writing lock file

Package operations: 3 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing typing-extensions (4.0.1)
  • Installing numpy (1.21.4)
  • Installing torch (1.10.0+cpu https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.10.0%2Bcpu-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl)
```

**NOTE:** Numpy has to be listed. Otherwise you'll get an import error.

Without numpy:

```
$ python
Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 23 2021, 00:34:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
/home/redqueen/machine_learning/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/package/_directory_reader.py:17: UserWarning: Failed to initialize NumPy: No module named 'numpy' (Triggered internally at  ../torch/csrc/utils/tensor_numpy.cpp:68.)
  _dtype_to_storage = {data_type(0).dtype: data_type for data_type in _storages}
>>> quit()
```

With numpy:

```
$ python
Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 23 2021, 00:34:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
>>> quit()
```

### Reference:

https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#python-restricted-dependencies

### Disclaimer

I do not have a Windows (or Mac) to test this on.

Comment: When I use this approach, Poetry will still download torch from this url every time I run `poetry lock`. Is there any way to avoid this, to your knowledge?

Comment: @roshambo I believe that's a bug with an open issue. See [here](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2415) or [here](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5902)

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to "get around" this by running `poetry lock --up-update`

Answer (score 5):

There is a fork that I am maintaining called [relaxed-poetry](https://github.com/bennylut/relaxed-poetry) It is a very young fork but it supports what you want with the following configuration:

```
# pyproject.toml

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
torch = { version = "=1.90+cu111", source = "pytorch" }

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "pytorch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/"
secondary = true
```

Check it if you like, it can be installed side by side with poetry.

Comment: This maybe a game changer for ML. Very difficult to use Poetry with pytorch currently.

Comment: Adding the poetry source lets me install the right version of pytorch but then I can't install anything else (e.g. black) because poetry searches only in download.pytorch.org

Comment: With poetry 1.5.0 it works with `priority = "supplemental"` instead of `secondary` https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#supplemental-package-sources

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for me (with GOU running CUDA 12.1 and Python 3.11 on Windows) in my toml file. You can find other versions of PyTorch (torch, torchaudio, torchvideo) to run at https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121 that are for CPU only, running on Windows, Linux and Mac

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
torch = {url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121/torch-2.2.1%2Bcu121-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl"}
torchaudio = {url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121/torchaudio-2.2.1%2Bcu121-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl"}
torchvision = {url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121/torchvision-0.17.1%2Bcu121-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl"}
```