# Cannot install torchvision via poetry in windows

Tags: python, pytorch, python-poetry

I succeeded in pytorch installation thanks to answers here
[Poetry and PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158044/poetry-and-pytorch).

But, I'm still failed to install torchvision via poetry.

```sh
> poetry add torchvision==0.8.2

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

Writing lock file

Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing torchvision (0.8.2)

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for torchvision (0.8.2)

  at ~\.poetry\lib\poetry\installation\chooser.py:72 in choose_for
       68│ 
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       71│         if not links:
    →  72│             raise RuntimeError(
       73│                 "Unable to find installation candidates for {}".format(package)
       74│             )
       75│
       76│         # Get the best link


Failed to add packages, reverting the pyproject.toml file to its original content.
```

I googled it and found some answers that say 'just `pip install torchvision`'.
But I'm suspicious that it works because according to PyPi(https://pypi.org/project/torchvision/#files), there is no wheel file for windows. And I tried it and it failed as I expected.

Is there any way to install latest torchvisin which is compatible with latest torch(1.7.1) in windows? + via poetry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Look in https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html for the version you want to install (torchvision version, python version, CUDA version, OS etc.)
2. Add a URL dependency to your `pyproject.toml` file. For example I have torchvision 1.8.0 working with the following in my dependencies

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
torch = {url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torch-1.8.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl"}
torchvision = {url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torchvision-0.9.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl"}
```

3. From your activated virtual environment do `poetry update torchvision` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, I just reopen terminal and all worked good. I guess I was in some wrong environment.