# Install GDAL on poetry project

Tags: python, gdal, python-poetry

I'm having trouble installing GDAL in a virtual environment managed by Poetry (working on an Ubuntu 18.04 distribution).

What I already found was:

- [this issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/845) on poetry github's repo; the pull request mentionned at the end seems to be stuck for now;
- one [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65187428/can-poetry-automatically-choose-a-package-version-based-on-the-version-of-the-co) on SO related to the gdal version configuration on poetry.

For a "standard" installation, there are [examples](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip#answer-74060) dealing with local paths using the "export" command.

So far, I haven't found any working example on how to install GDAL in a poetry project.

Does anybody know how to handle this? (or if this is possible at all?)

Comment: So far I've also found [what may be a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158044/poetry-and-pytorch#answer-66644457) though I haven't been able to make it work. I have also been able to use a workaround (which I will post as an answer but I won't accept it yet in case somebody has a better answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A workaround is to :

1. run the shell (and start the virtual environment configured by poetry);
2. proceed to install gdal using pip (beeing aware of the versions and needed option as stated [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip#answer-74060) for instance);
3. exit the shell;
4. proceed to mimic an new install through poetry (`poetry add gdal==X.X.X`);
5. poetry should update the lock and toml files and conclude that no dependencies need to be installed or updated.

As I said this is a workaround (which needs to be referenced for now).

I hope a better solution will emerge and will keep this "solution" unaccepted for a while...

Comment: Another workaround might be to install Fiona or rasterio (depending on what you use GDAL for): both are available as wheels on pypi and include the shared library of GDAL (this is a recent developpement concerning Fiona, I'm not sure about rasterio).